# Error when extracting sub-string from the start of source string in C

Tags: arrays, c, string, function

This is from an exercise in Chapter 9 of Programming in C 4th Edition. The programme is to read in characters into a string and extract a portion of the string into a sub-string by specifying a start position and number of characters.
The programme compiles and runs well except when the zeroth position of the source is stated as the start. Nothing is then displayed.
This is my code.

```
/* Programme to extract a portion from a string using function
sub-string (source, start, count, result) ex9.4.c

ALGORITHM
Get text input into a char array (declare to be fixed size);
Determine length of source string;
Prepare result array to be dynamic length using desired count + 1;
Copy from source array into result array

*/

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#define MAX 501

void read_Line (char buffer[]);
int string_Length (char string[]);
void sub_String (char source[], int start, int count, char result[]);

int main(void)
{
    char strSource[MAX];
    bool end_Of_Text = false;
    int strCount = 0;
    printf("This is a programme to extract a sub-string from a source string.\n");


    printf("\nType in your text (up to 500 characters).\n");
    printf("When you are done, press 'RETURN or ENTER'.\n\n");

    while (! end_Of_Text)
    {
        read_Line(strSource);

        if (strSource[0] == '\0')
        {
            end_Of_Text = true;
        }
        else
        {
            strCount += string_Length(strSource);
        }
    }

    // Declare variables to store sub-string parameters
    int subStart, subCount;
    char subResult[MAX];

    printf("Enter start position for sub-string: ");
    scanf(" %i", &subStart);
    getchar();

    printf("Enter number of characters to extract: ");
    scanf(" %i", &subCount);
    getchar();

    // Call sub-string function
    sub_String(strSource, subStart, subCount, subResult);

    return 0;

}

// Function to get text input
void read_Line (char buffer[])
{
    char character;
    int i = 0;

    do
    {
        character = getchar();
        buffer[i] = character;
        ++i;
    }
    while (character != '\n');

    buffer[i - 1] = '\0';
}

// Function to count determine the length of a string
int string_Length (char string[])
{
    int len = 0;

    while (string[len] != '\0')
    {
        ++len;
    }

    return len;
}

// Function to extract substring
void sub_String (char source[], int start, int count, char result[])
{
    int i, j, k;

    k = start + count;

    for (i = start, j = 0; i < k || i == '\0'; ++i, ++j)
    {
        result[j] = source[i];
    }

    result[k] = '\0';

    printf("%s\n", result);
}
```

I am using Code::Blocks on Linux Mint.

Comment: STRONG SUGGESTION: step through your code in the debugger to troubleshoot "what's wrong": https://www.dummies.com/programming/c/how-to-use-the-codeblocks-debugger-with-c-programming/

Comment: Fyi, `result[k] = '\0';` in your substring algorithm should be `result[j] = '\0';`

Comment: Nit: this probably doesn't affect the case you asked about, but in sub_String(), the loop condition `i < k || i == '\0'` is not quite right. It should be an && instead of ||, and you want `source[i] != '\0'`, not `i == '\0'`.

Comment: Since you have provided a self-answer, you should probably remove the answer from the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Being someone that just started learning programming recently with CS50 and 'Programming in C' books, I did not know how to setup the debugger in Code::Blocks. But thanks to the push by @paulsm4, I managed to get the debugger working. Using the watches window of the debugger, I could see that the while loop in the main function was overwriting the first character in the source array with a null character. The fix was to add a break statement. Thanks to @WhozCraig and @Pascal Getreuer for pointing out other errors that I had missed. This is the corrected code now:

```
/* Programme to extract a portion from a string using function
sub-string (source, start, count, result) ex9.4.c

ALGORITHM
Get text input into a char array (declare to be fixed size);
Determine length of source string;
Prepare result array to be dynamic length using desired count + 1;
Copy from source array into result array

*/

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#define MAX 501

void read_Line (char buffer[]);
int string_Length (char string[]);
void sub_String (char source[], int start, int count, char result[]);

int main(void)
{
    char strSource[MAX];
    bool end_Of_Text = false;
    int strCount = 0;
    printf("This is a programme to extract a sub-string from a source string.\n");


    printf("\nType in your text (up to 500 characters).\n");
    printf("When you are done, press 'RETURN or ENTER'.\n\n");

    while (! end_Of_Text)
    {
        read_Line(strSource);

        if (strSource[0] == '\0')
        {
            end_Of_Text = true;
        }
        else
        {
            strCount += string_Length(strSource);
        }
        break;
    }

    // Declare variables to store sub-string parameters
    int subStart, subCount;
    char subResult[MAX];

    printf("Enter start position for sub-string: ");
    scanf(" %i", &subStart);
    getchar();

    printf("Enter number of characters to extract: ");
    scanf(" %i", &subCount);
    getchar();

    // Call sub-string function
    sub_String(strSource, subStart, subCount, subResult);

    return 0;

}

// Function to get text input
void read_Line (char buffer[])
{
    char character;
    int i = 0;

    do
    {
        character = getchar();
        buffer[i] = character;
        ++i;
    }
    while (character != '\n');

    buffer[i - 1] = '\0';
}

// Function to count determine the length of a string
int string_Length (char string[])
{
    int len = 0;

    while (string[len] != '\0')
    {
        ++len;
    }

    return len;
}

// Function to extract substring
void sub_String (char source[], int start, int count, char result[])
{
    int i, j, k;

    k = start + count;

    // Source[i] == '\0' is used in case count exceeds source string length
    for (i = start, j = 0; i < k || source[i] == '\0'; ++i, ++j)
    {
        result[j] = source[i];
    }

    result[j] = '\0';

    printf("%s\n", result);
}
```